# String is not recognized as valid date time

Tags: c#, datetime

**Description:**

In my application user is allowed to insert date in string format EX- "01/01/2000"and I'm parsing this string value using `DateTime.Parse("01/01/00");` it is working fine. But in few case it is breaking.

**Case 1:**

Input : "01/01/00"

Code: DateTime.Parse("01/01/00");

Output: 01/01/2000

**Case 2:**

Input : "01/01/000"

Code: DateTime.Parse("01/01/000");

Output: Getting error "String is not recognized as valid date time."

**Case 3:**

Input : "01/01/0000"

Code: DateTime.Parse("01/01/0000");

Output: Getting error "String is not recognized as valid date time."

How to parse 000 or 0000 as correct year ?

Comment: What do you expect as outcome?

Comment: "How to parse 000 or 0000 as correct year ?"  Good question.  How indeed.

Comment: Kind of hard considering DateTime can't represent year 0... What result you expect in cases 2/3?

Comment: why would you allow the user to enter the year `0000`? does the application process historical chronological data?

Comment: @ Romano Zumbé I want "000 or 0000" should be parsed in correct year(2000). When we enter 00 or 000 or 0000 in datepicker it take it as 2000 then I'm not getting why DateTime.Parse("01/01/0000"); is throwing an error ?

Comment: Is there a Date Format with 3 digits in the year "000" ? I think the answer is "NO". Thus, it does not convert in case 3.

Comment: @Mong Zhu - yes, application process historical data.

Comment: @user7745736 So how do you distinguish year 10, 1910 and 2010 when the user enters "01/01/10"?

Comment: @user7745736 If your application processes historical data then you should probably be aware that there is no year zero. 31st December 1 BCE is followed by 1st January 1 CE.

Comment: @user7745736 `0000` should be parsed in correct year(2000) ???

Comment: you want the outcome to be `2000` whereas `0000` is clearly not `2000` I don't see the point of allowing this as correct input. I meant with historical data, that you really need the year `0` where the counting of years for the western world began.

Comment: @JDoshi - yes, there is a date format with  year "000", check Date in console using new Date("01/01/000"), you will get "Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Comment: What do you get when you enter "01/01/0000"??

Comment: DateTime.Minvalue = The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000 UTC, January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar. as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @STLDeveloper
 In javascript - 
   Code : new Date("01/01/0000") 
    Output: Sat Jan 01 2000 

In C# -
   Code : DateTime.Parse("01/01/0000");
   Output:  getting error "String is not recognized as valid date time."

Comment: What do you expect if user input '01/01/945'?

Comment: @Mong Zhu - There is a date format with year "0000", please check Date in console using new Date("01/01/0000"), you will get "Sat Jan 01 2000"

Comment: @Ikram - If user input "01/01/945" then expected output will be same "01/01/945"

Comment: @user7745736 Javascript? In nowhere in your question are you talking about javascript and the question is tagged with ***c#*** you are making no sense here.

Comment: @Esko My question is about C# only, I'm just saying "01/01/0000" is valid in java script then why C# is throwing an error?.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Noda Time library.  It supports a very large range of dates in various geographical areas and conversions between such.  See http://nodatime.org

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it with below extension method

```
public static DateTime GetDateTime(this string strdate)
{
    int day = Convert.ToInt32(strdate.Split('/')[0]);
    int month = Convert.ToInt32(strdate.Split('/')[1]);
    int year = Convert.ToInt32(strdate.Split('/')[2]);

    if (year == 0)
        year = 2000;

    return new DateTime(year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check your inputs you type input="**01/01/000**" it adds an extra zero and makes value="**01/01/0000**" which does not exist and thus throws exception. try 
input="**01/01/100**" and you will get output as "**01/01/0100**" 
range is limited to last two digits and if you type any number in range of (**00 to 29**) you will get date in 2000+ ie if input=("**01/01/29**") you get output=("**01/01/2029**") but if you type input=("**01/01/30"**) you will get output=("**01/01/1930**")

Answer (score 0):

When you are validating date then you should keep in mind that the valid and invalid date format should be like this:

**Valid Dates: "02/02/0002", "02/02/02"

Invalid Dates: "02/02/002", "02/02/00002"**

Please find the code below for your reference. I think this is self-explanatory.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Valid Dates: "02/02/0002", "02/02/02"        
        //Invalid Dates: "02/02/002", "02/02/00002"        
        string date = "02/02/02";
        bool validDate = isDateTimeFormatValid(date);
        string status = validDate ? "valid" : "invalid";
        Console.WriteLine(date + " is " + status + " date");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private static bool isDateTimeFormatValid(string date)
    {
        DateTime dateResult;
        bool chkYY = false;
        bool chkYYYY = false;
        if (date.Contains("/"))
        {
            chkYY = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                             DateTimeStyles.None, out dateResult);
            chkYYYY = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                             DateTimeStyles.None, out dateResult);
        }
        //Performing OR Operation
        bool result = chkYY | chkYYYY;
        return result;
    }
}
```